# CQL Datastax Java Mapping Set/List query operations

Tags: cassandra, orm, datastax, codec

Hi I am currently trying to setup my CQL Dao in order to implement some query functions,
however I can't find a way to put a Collection of any objects as an argument because I keep getting this error with the codec: `Codec not found for requested operation: [TEXT <-> java.util.List<java.lang.String>]`

I tried using this but it didn't work:

```kotlin
@Select(customWhereClause = "labels CONTAINS :labels", perPartitionLimit = "1")
fun dependenciesByLabels(@CqlName("labels") labels: Collection<String>): PagingIterable<Dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess my acknowledge in Cassandra were not enough. Indeed, it seems that we can the CONTAINS cassandra operator on Collections with multiple values:

**This works**:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE labels CONTAINS 'label';
```

**This doesn't work**:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE labels CONTAINS { 'label1', 'label2' };
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to define a codec for your collection, there are some examples here:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/custom_codecs/#creating-custom-codecs-for-user-defined-types-ud-ts
If that doesn't help, please include your collection/type definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
Codec not found for requested operation: [TEXT <-> java.util.List<java.lang.String>]
```

So this error message means that you're trying to map a column defined as `TEXT` (UTF string) to a Java `List<String>`.

It definitely looks like you're using a collection on the app side, so I would check the table definition and make sure that the column is defined as a `List<TEXT>`.